# Apache Async HTTP send requests with new Proxy on each Request

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient

I have to check thousands of proxy servers continuously.

To speed it up, I am thinking to create a batch of size N(say 50) and send requests to them concurrently. Each proxy server has a unique IP/Port and username/password authentication.

Since I am checking proxies, I will configure the request to use the given Proxy and send a request to the target site and measure the response.

Here is an example to use proxy with auth from the Apache client docs:

```
 public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("localhost", 8889),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("squid", "nopassword"));
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
                .build();
        try {
            httpclient.start();
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("localhost", 8889);
            RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                    .setProxy(proxy)
                    .build();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://httpbin.org/");
            httpget.setConfig(config);
            Future<HttpResponse> future = httpclient.execute(httpget, null);
            HttpResponse response = future.get();
            System.out.println("Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println("Shutting down");
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, if you are using an authenticated proxy, you need to provide the credentials in the Client itself. 
This means that if I am checking 50 proxy servers concurrently then I have to create a new client for each of them. Which means that the requests will not be concurrent and better if I just use a multi-threaded solution.

The issue is that if I use multithreading then I will put excessive loads on the server as most of the threads will block on I/O. A concurrent non-blocking I/O is much better for this type of challenge.

How can I check multiple authenticated proxy servers concurrently if I have to create a client for each of them?

Comment: *This means that if I am checking 50 proxy servers concurrently then I have to create a new client* why is that ? You can provide credentials provider per request if I recall correctly just like you do for proxy,.

Comment: *you need to provide the credentials in the Client itself.* Thats actually **default** provider, so you can provide custom one as well.

Comment: Besides if you must do it thiat way, all you need to do is to add credentials for proxy you are about to use to that provider.